# Reality Converter Beta 3 – Error in GLTF to USDZ conversion

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, gltf, realitykit, reality-composer

I am currently using a `.glTF` model which is perfectly fine inside a `.glTF` viewer. However as soon as I try converting it to `.usdz` to use within ARKit, I get this error :

```
USDZ Conversion Failed: An error occurred in converting 
this file to USDZ. Please check the errors for details.
```

**I am unable to find where the error is listed**.

Can someone please help with this. It is my first time experimenting with 3D and ARKit.